# C++ Strange File Output

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read from a simple text file. Whenever I run the program it prints out the file, 
but not before printing out a bunch of garble. Any suggestions?

Garble:

```
Φ#·  ├ï Uï∞ Φ╖   ≈╪←└≈╪YH]├ 5tδ╝
 abc
```

Buffer.cc

```
//-----------------------------------------------------
//  TextInputBuffer  - Constructor for TextInputBuffer.
//-----------------------------------------------------
TextInputBuffer::TextInputBuffer(char *InputFileName)
{
    //--Open file. Abort if failed.
    InputFile.open(InputFileName, std::ios::in);
    if (!InputFile.good()) exit(1);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------
//  GetNextLine      - Get next line from input file.
//
//  Return: The first character of the next line.
//-----------------------------------------------------
char TextInputBuffer::GetNextLine()
{
    //--Get next line from input file.
if (InputFile.eof()) *ptrChar = eofChar;
else
{
    InputFile.getline(Text, MaxInputBufferSize);
    ptrChar = Text;
}

return *ptrChar;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------
//  GetNextChar      - Get next character from the text
//                     buffer.
//
//  Return: The next character in the text buffer.
//-----------------------------------------------------
char TextInputBuffer::GetNextChar()
{
    char ch;

    if      (*ptrChar == eofChar) ch = eofChar;
    else if (*ptrChar == eolChar) ch = GetNextLine();
    else
    {
        ++ptrChar;
        ch = *ptrChar;
    }

    return ch;
}
```

List.cc

```
TextInputBuffer InputBuffer(argv[1]);
char ch;

do {
    ch = InputBuffer.GetNextChar();

    if (ch == eolChar)
        std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << ch;
} while (ch != eofChar);
```

Comment: You might try a really low level text editor or hex dump on the first few long words of the file to try to match the "bunch of garble".

Comment: No, it isn't low-level enough, as it's easily confused by different character encodings (lack of BOM being particularly problematic). Use a hex editor.

Comment: I just did and it only 616263 (aka abc.) I also think that MRAB is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's reading the first line after opening the file, so it's fetching junk characters from the uninitialised line storage until one happens to be the newline character, at which point it actually reads the first line.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with some idiomatic code to read and display your data. If that doesn't work then there's a pretty fair chance your input file doesn't contain what you expected. If it does work, then the problem you're seeing is somewhere in your existing code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char**argv) { 
    std::ifstream in(argv[1]);
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(in, line))
        std::cout << line << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Right now, you seem to be using iostreams, but using them just oddly enough that it's hard to guess whether you might be doing something wrong, and if so exactly what. In any case, virtually all of your code seems to be attempting to duplicate things iostreams (and streambuffers) already do anyway. If you really just want to read one character at a time, do that. Attempting to write your own buffering is *usually* a waste of time; if/when it really isn't, you're generally better off writing your buffering code in an actual stream buffer, not as a wrapper around an iostream.